Why does "Prefix: " + 'abc' in 'abcdef' evaluate to False rather than 'Prefix: True'?
I am new to python and trying this code out
course = 'Python for Beginners'
print("Python is in text: " + 'Python' in course)

I was expecting the Output
Python is in text: True

The Result I actually get is just the Boolean value below.
False

I know I can fix the code by adding a str and a parenthesis around str('Python' in course), however I would like to understand the mechanism of what is going on in my original code.
Can any of you explain how the Python parses the code.
I see that Python can parse logical operators without Parenthesis i.e.
value = 15
print(value > 10 and value < 30)


For the first, see Python's Operator Precedence. For the second, that does print True. See Comparison Chaining for how that's interpreted though.

Oops, I misinterpreted the question a bit. Still, those links will answer a lot for you.

If it were parsed as you expected, wouldn't you expect an error because you can't concatenate a string and boolean?

Operators in Python execute according to operator precedence. An operator with higher precedence will be executed earlier than one with lower precedence.
In your case we have two operators: string concatenation (+) and some type of membership test (in).
So if we check operator precedence we find out that + is executed earlier than in because it has higher precedence. Also in the table of precedence, we see that expressions inside parentheses have highest precedence: use them when you need to explicitly set order of operator execution.

To OP, please use the official docs instead: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence. GeeksForGeeks is exceedingly low quality.

@Carcigenicate oh yeah, sorry, my bad

@iggi
so do you mean at first, Python is parsing "Python is in text: " + 'Python'
So the output is: "Python is in text: Python"
Now it is trying to Find - "Python is in text: Python"  in the String Course and hence it returns False?

@user25235025 yes, exactly

An additional note to the answer already provided, which is quite right, using f-strings would entirely sidestep this issue, forcing a disambiguating set of braces.
course = 'Python for Beginners'
print(f"Python is in text: {'Python' in course}")

Resulting of course in:
Python is in text: True


Or let print handle it for you: print("Python is in text:", 'Python' in course). It's easier to write and read, but can be harder to change later.

That works too. I like the directness of the f-string and knowing exactly where spaces will be without having to think about the separator being used.
